# do sum filter by date

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

In my business what I do is provide a book of 25 coupon. If customer buys anything (from special people say Person A, Person B, etc to whom I give coupon), Person A gives one coupon to the customer. What I am doing is maintaining database of the same in excel. First column have coupon code. Then Date on which I took details. Then Sold column where I put daily details of sold coupons. Then I have Remaining coupon column and finally the total coupon left from the respective coupon book

Data looks like below.

```
Coupon #    Date    Sold    Remaining   Starting Day Coupon Counter
Coupon A    22-Oct-12   22  3   25
Coupon B    22-Oct-12   16  9   25
Coupon C    22-Oct-12   24  1   25
Coupon A    23-Oct-12   3   0   3
Coupon B    23-Oct-12   9   0   9
Coupon C    23-Oct-12   1   0   1
Coupon D    23-Oct-12   5   20  25
Coupon E    23-Oct-12   8   17  25
Coupon F    23-Oct-12   2   23  25
Coupon D    24-Oct-12   20  0   20
Coupon E    24-Oct-12   17  0   17
Coupon F    24-Oct-12   23  0   23
```

What I want is **same data** for the respective date. Output I am looking is as below.

```
Date    Sold    Remaining   Starting Day Coupon Counter
22-Oct-12   62  13  75
23-Oct-12   28  60  88
24-Oct-12   60  0   60
```

Any idea to get this done? I know how to get sum, but not sure how to filter it by any stuff.

### Edit 1

I know thiis can be done using Macro, however I want to use pre-defined function available in excel.

Any idea/ suggestions how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-build your report sheet with dates, then use SUMIF like so:

`=SUMIF(date range, date cell (date to get information for), entire column to sum for)`

This uses french formulas but you should be able to make it work with your workbook knowing it is in fact `SUMIF`.

[image]

Comment: Just noticed that the leftmost column shows numbers instead of proper dates. The formatting seems to have been lost when using the "show formulas" option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I shall check and get back to you tomorrow, as I am replying from mobile now.

Comment: I checcked your answer and its working. But one problem is that I will need to write Date column manually. How could I get date column ussing formulae? Like in mysql it could be distinct(date), but not sure how to get this done in excel?

Comment: Usually what I do in this case is use a pivot table and put only that field in the row data section. The pivot table will automatically show only unique elements and then you can copy paste that into your data range where you will do the analysis. If that is too much work you can probably use the macro recorder for this as it is a pretty simple task. If you know VBA you can code it but I think the macro recorder is your best bet here.