# list distinct values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

***This question is related to*** [***this question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112163/do-sum-filter-by-date).

I have data as below.

```
 Col A
22-Oct-12
22-Oct-12
22-Oct-12
23-Oct-12
23-Oct-12
23-Oct-12
23-Oct-12
23-Oct-12
23-Oct-12
24-Oct-12
24-Oct-12
24-Oct-12
```

What I want is find the unique values in column B so that output would be as below.

```
 Col A
22-Oct-12
23-Oct-12
24-Oct-12
```

I tried with `=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1,A1,"")` but the problem is that I get `22-Oct-12` infront of first occurrence of `22-Oct-12`, `23-Oct-12` infront of first occurrence of `23-Oct-12`. Output is shown as below.

```
 Col A       Col B
22-Oct-12   22-Oct-12
22-Oct-12   
22-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   23-Oct-12
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
24-Oct-12   24-Oct-12
24-Oct-12   
24-Oct-12
```

**I don't want output like this. What I want is as below.**

```
 Col A       Col B
22-Oct-12   22-Oct-12
22-Oct-12   23-Oct-12
22-Oct-12   24-Oct-12
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
24-Oct-12   
24-Oct-12   
24-Oct-12
```

### OR

```
 Col A      Col B          Col C
22-Oct-12   22-Oct-12   22-Oct-12
22-Oct-12               23-Oct-12
22-Oct-12               24-Oct-12
23-Oct-12   23-Oct-12
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
23-Oct-12   
24-Oct-12   24-Oct-12
24-Oct-12   
24-Oct-12
```

***Note :*** I can do this by MACRO, however I don't want to use MACRO. I want to get this done by use of excel functions.

Also, I could do above as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-values-in-a-column-in-excel), however I don't want to get done manually.

Everything by pre-defined excel function. NO MACRO or NO MANUAL WORK.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this article - http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/04/14/create-a-unique-alphabetically-sorted-list-extracted-from-a-column/

Comment: You can also check out this article, http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming numeric data (e.g. numbers or dates).....

In B1 use this formula

`=MIN(A1:A1000)`

and then in B2 (assuming Excel 2007 or later)

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(A$1:A$1000>B1,A$1:A$1000),1),"")`

...or in earlier Excel versions

`=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A$1000,">"&B1),MIN(IF(A$1:A$1000>B1,A$1:A$1000)),"")`

confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and copy down

If you have more than 1000 rows of data adjust accordingly.

This method will list dates in chronological order without repeats however they are ordered within the data

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and use `CONTROL + SHIFT + ENTER`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($B$1:B1;$A$2:$A$20);0));"")
```